# VueJs + Firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuefire

I'm starting to use VueJS with Firebase (and VueFire), but I'm starting to struggle a bit about how to structure the data.

My case is pretty simple.

I have a list of suppliers and a list of products.

A product can only be linked to one supplier, and a supplier can have multiple products.

And I have different views :

- List of all products for all suppliers
- List of products for one supplier
- Detail of one product with the supplier.

For the 1st and 2nd views, I have no issue with the following structure

```
products
    - productKey1
        - name : Product1
    - productKey2
        - name : Product2
supplier-products:
    - supplierKey1
        - productKey1
             - name : Product1
    - supplierKey2
        - productKey2
             - name : Product2
supplier:
    - supplierKey1
         - name : Supplier1
    - supplierKey2
         - name : Supplier2
```

I can easily show a list of all products from "/products" and for each supplier from "supplier-products/supplierKey"

But what about a view with the product detail + the supplier detail.

What is the best way to do that ?

- Adding the supplier information into each products ?
- Add a kind of foreign key into products ?
- Another way to do it ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem in my app, where I have a similar relationship between Businesses and Locations. I have found that the best solution is to have a store for Businesses, a store for Locations, and a store for the joins between them.

In your case:

```
products: [
  { productKey: 1, name: 'Product1' },
  { productKey: 2, name: 'Product2' },
],
suppliers: [
  { supplierKey: 1, name: 'Supplier1' },
  { supplierKey: 2, name: 'Supplier2' },
],
supplierProducts: [
  { productKey: 1, supplierKey: 1 },
  { productKey: 2, supplierKey: 2 },
]
```

Now, you can easily filter the list of `supplierProducts` by the currently selected `supplierKey`, or the currently selected `productKey`, and then use the opposite key to pull the right list for your view.

Answer (score 0):

While I do respect your choice of using Firebase, I would have opted for an SQL database for your case because you're gonna have a lot of relations.

aidangarza's answer is one way to do it but it also expensive when thinking in long term. Firebase will count your reads every time you query from `supplierProducts` and then when you want to show all the `products` and `suppliers` data that are linked.

Let's say a supplier has 300 products, every time you want to query all products linked to that supplier, Firebase will count 300 reads.

So, what I recommend you is to assign every product to a supplier et then copy the product data to the supplier data :

```
"products": {
    "productKey1": {
      "name": "Product1",
      "supplierKey": "supplierKey1"
    }
}


 "supplier-products":{
    "supplierKey1":[
      {"id":"productKey1", "name" : "Product1"}
    ],
    "supplierKey2":[
      {"id":"productKey4", "name" : "Product4"},
      {"id":"productKey10", "name" : "Product10"},
      {"id":"productKey15", "name" : "Product15"}
    ],
    "supplierKey3":[
      {"id":"productKey5", "name" : "Product5"}
    ]
}
```

Now, if you want to fetch all the products from X supplier, you simply have to fetch data from (supplier-products/supplierKeyX). Firebase will only count this as 1 read instead of the total amount of products linked to supplier X.

If you worry on how you're gonna need to update all the references of a product if for ex. the name changes. I recommend you watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1n9Kw3AORw) that talks about Multi-path updates.

After all, denormalization is the core of NoSQL databases, if there are to much relations between collections, it will be very hard to maintain your NoSQL DB.